# MPMediaPickerController customize the colors of the labels and icons

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, xcode5, mpmediapickercontroller

I need change the labels colors of `MPMediaPickerController` item, on iOS 7 , im using `Xcode5`, what can i do?.

My code of the creation of `MPMediaPickerController` is:

```
- (IBAction)addSongs:(id)sender {
  MPMediaPickerController *picker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeMusic];
  picker.delegate = self;
  picker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = YES;  
}
```

I was trying with this but not works: https://gist.github.com/acidlemon/1955332

Examples:[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your tab bar's `tintColor` using the appearance proxy, e.g.:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
```

To change the `tintColor` of all views, including your label, you can do the following in your AppDelegate.m file:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{    
    [[UIView appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: you know if is possible change the gray background color or the icons?

Comment: @GonzaloBahamondez Please ask those in separate questions. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22134898/mpmediapickercontroller-background-colors-of-icons-when-arent-selected