# MPMediaPickerController background colors of icons, when aren´t selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, mpmediapickercontroller

I need change the gray color of the icons in MPMediaPickerController,  when they are not selected, and the background is opaque, like faded, i need remove this too.

i'm using ios7.1  and the next code to show MPMediaPickerController element, on my viewController.

```
- (IBAction)addSongs:(id)sender {

  MPMediaPickerController *picker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc]
                                  initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeMusic];

  picker.delegate = self;
  picker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = YES;

  [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

And this code on AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
      didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {



  [[UIView appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

  return YES;
}
```

example:

[image]

Comment: Try getting the view of your picker and try changing the alpha setting.

Comment: @GonzaloBahamondez I have set my title position in appdelegate like this [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0.0, -12.0)]; But now In another View controller I need tab bar item title at default position???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the same as [MPMediaPickerController customize the colors of the labels and icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22106313/mpmediapickercontroller-customize-the-colors-of-the-labels-and-icons?lq=1)

....
 in the app delegate :

```
 [[UIView appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

the command sets the colour tone for tab bars, toolbars, etc everything with a sillohouette icon....   Your tab bar seems seems to be translucent over a dark window background ....   I use mpmediapickercontroller too in my app and I get an all white background with the default setting since moving to IOS 7. I believe it is your windows.backgroundcolor  mine is set to white.

Comment: No, is not the same, this doesn't work , this way works fine for color of  selected icon, and the worst is , in the last update of ios 7.1 , this not working anymore, now  the selected item is green, is ignoring the color of the sentence:

    [[UIView appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]]; 

I dont understand.

Comment: Gonzalo I understand your frustration, the MPMediaController does not really have the controls that will allow programmers to change and modify its appearance. I suspect that Apple wants it to look and feel like the music app and apple can take what little way you can to change the appearance anytime.     On the other hand there are enough commands to allow you to select all the media available in the media library so you can make your own picker. With regards to the dull gray colour, is there any song in the media library I suspect it behaves that way because there is no music.

Comment: Can you give me a little reference of how create my own picker, for give you the bounty , and close the question?

Comment: Sure -  You can use a class called  MPMediaQuery to extract the media/ songs into an array then use a tableview for a picker.   - Look at this page - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/AboutiPodLibraryAccess/AboutiPodLibraryAccess.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008765-CH103-SW9

Comment: @Paulo what to do if i want to set Background color in MPMediaPickerController in ios 8 or above